# Foundation icons won't show

Tags: css, svg, icons, zurb-foundation

I am now taking care of a website built on Zurb Foundation, the previous developer made some custom icons (like 15) for that website using the foundation syntax - He took the **i** tag in all CSS files  and renamed the CSS variables like .icons-custom-phone   .The foundation-icons.css is added to the page and all the font files are on the server but when i try to name a class="fi-phone" it won't show...  as he added a custom.css  just after the  foundation-icons.css and created custom.svg custom.eot custom.woff  etc.

I was wondering how can use the foundation icons in that case since some are really nice

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check out for errors, maybe you're not calling fonts at all, check paths etc.

Comment: I inspected the element, it's  calling  the i tag in the custom.css with the custom font-family.  foundation-icons.css is listed at the bottom but it seems it is ignored.